# Screenshots for iPhone 4/5/6/6+/iPad

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, app-store-connect, screen-capture

I must attend to edit screenshots for an application, available on iPhone and iPad in 14 different languages.
Each screenshot contains a text explaining the screen in all 14 languages.
As each iPhone requires a different image size on iTunes Connect, so I have to edit: 14 x 5 x 5 screenshots different resolutions. This makes a total of 350 screenshots for iTunes Connect, just for one app.

My question is: there's there a simpler solution, less tedious than having to edit each screen in each size in Photoshop?
Thank You

Answer (score 1):

There are solutions to automating editing and generation of App Store screenshots. Whether you find them 'simpler' depends a bit on what tools you're comfortable using:

**Editing existing screenshots?**
If you're adding frames and title texts, you can automate this with [FrameIt](https://github.com/fastlane/frameit) (if you are comfortable working in the command line).
Other generic image editing problems: Use [Adobe Photoshop](http://www.adobe.com/products/photoshop.html) and make friends with the Actions palette.

**Generating new screenshots?**
Automate generating new screenshots across devices and languages with [Snapshot](https://github.com/KrauseFx/snapshot), this relies on learning a bit of the [Instruments app](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) and specifically [UI Automation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/UsingtheAutomationInstrument/UsingtheAutomationInstrument.html), and some command line fiddling.

If I were to recommend, I would work through automating generating new screenshots rather than fiddle with editing existing screenshots. This might have a harder learning curve, but once done you should save a lot of time when preparing screenshots for future versions of the app.

[Snapshot](https://github.com/KrauseFx/snapshot) and [FrameIt](https://github.com/fastlane/frameit) are both part of [Fastlane toolset](https://fastlane.tools) for automating the App Store submission process.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this app in the Mac App store: https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/prepo/id476533227?mt=12

[image]

I'm not sure this does exactly what you need, but it's a free app for most features and may be worth a try.